# Empty Maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap

I keep getting empty maps when i am passing data into two hash maps in clojure, i know that the data is being sent through the functions as i have used print statements that show it correct data, its just when i assoc the data to the map it doesnt appear to do anything and leaves me with {}

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong??

```
(defn sort-string [y]
  (apply str (sort y)))

(defn get-unique [y]
  (let [x (sort-string (str/lower-case y))
        hashmap1 (hash-map)
        hashmap2 (hash-map)]

    (if-not (contains? hashmap1 x)
      (assoc hashmap1 x, y)
      (assoc hashmap2 y, y))

    (if-not (get hashmap1 x) y)
    (dissoc hashmap2 (get hashmap1 x))))

(for [strings '("door" " rood" "pen" "open" "high" "low" "wall" "lawl" "#")]
  (get-unique strings))
```

Comment: What is the output you're expecting from this?

Comment: minor issues: `(hash-map)` is an unconventional way of writing `{}`, that `contains?` check will never return true, because the hash map it is checking is 100% guaranteed to be empty in all cases.

Comment: According to your comment on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35117301/1562315), you are trying to group anagrams together, using `sort-string` to produce something that is the same for all anagrams and for nothing else. *Please incorporate this into your question.*

Answer (score 1):

Clojure maps are immutable. So the `assoc`s, which *return* modified maps, have no effect, as the returned values are not used.

I don't know what you're trying to do, but the following might get you on the right lines:

```
(defn get-unique [y]
  (let [x (sort-string (str/lower-case y))
        hashmap1 (hash-map)
        hashmap2 (hash-map)
        [hashmap1 hashmap2]  (if-not (contains? hashmap1 x)
                               [(assoc hashmap1 x, y) (assoc hashmap2 y, y)]
                               [hashmap1 hashmap2])]

    (if-not (= (get hashmap1 x) y)
      (dissoc hashmap2 (get hashmap1 x))
      hashmap2)))
```

For example,

```
(for [strings '("door" " rood" "pen" "open" "high" "low" "wall" "lawl" "#")]
  (get-unique strings))

;({"door" "door"} {" rood" " rood"} {"pen" "pen"} {"open" "open"} {"high" "high"} {"low" "low"} {"wall" "wall"} {"lawl" "lawl"} {"#" "#"})
```

---

Now that your comment tells me you are trying to group anagrams together, using `sort-string` to test for equivalences ...

You can do this using `group-by`. For example,

```
(let [strings '("door" " rood" "pen" "open" "high" "low" "wall" "lawl" "#")]
  (group-by sort-string strings))
```

... produces ...

```
{"door" ["door" "rood"], "enp" ["pen"], "enop" ["open"], "ghhi" ["high"], "low" ["low"], "allw" ["wall" "lawl"], "#" ["#"]}
```

Comment: Is there a way to add X as the key and Y as the value to my map??

Comment: @ElliottSmelliott Use the returned value from the `assoc`, as above and in @Munk's answer.

Comment: Thats sort of what i need but i only want to return unique strings, so out of "door" "rood" odor" "pen"  only pen is returned as the other three can make up the other words rood = door + odor but pen is unique as no other words match pen

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake you're making is assuming `hashmap1` and `hashmap2` are mutable. `assoc` returns a new hashmap with the associated key and value, but the original remains unchanged.

You can see this in a repl like so:

```
user=> (def my-map {:a 1 :b 2})
#'user/my-map
user=> my-map
{:a 1, :b 2}
user=> (assoc my-map :c 3)
{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
user=> my-map
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

This means your block:

```
(if-not (contains? hashmap1 x)
  (assoc hashmap1 x, y)
  (assoc hashmap2 y, y))
```

just created a new hashmap with x as a key and y as a value and threw didn't do anything with it.

Maybe you could write another function to create the new map and return it like so:

```
(defn add-if-not-contains [m1 m2 x y]
    (if-not (contains? m1 x)
        [(assoc m1 x y) m2]
        [m1 (assoc m2 y y)]))
```

But your solution is still overly complicated I think. I'm guessing you want a single sorted element that does not have any other permutations in the list.

```
user=> (def my-strings ["door" " rood" "pen" "open" "high" "low" "wall" "lawl" "#"])
#'user/my-string

user=> (distinct (map sort-string my-strings))      
("door" " door" "enp" "enop" "ghhi" "low" "allw" "#")
```

If you want to just get words that have no permutation, you might try something like this

```
(frequencies (map sort-string ["door" "rood" "odor" "pen"]))
{"door" 3, "enp" 1}
```

Filtering that result to find entries with a value of 1 and finding the original word from the permutation are left as an exercise.

Comment: So with that new function there, would i run that inside of the get-unique function then i would be able to print out the map using something like tihs `(defn print-map [m]
  (prn "print map", m)
  (for [[x,y] (seq m)] (println (str x " : " y))))`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're thinking exactly, but I suspect you're not understanding the point about immutability yet. Try it out in a repl and see what it does.

Comment: What im trying to do is for example an input of "door" "rood" "odor" "pen".
Only return "pen" as when the others are sorted they are the same word. "pen" is the only one that cant be made up from any other string