# Checking String equals hash-map value Clojure - Cannot be cast

Tags: clojure, hashmap

So i have a function that i am doing two if statements on, the first one appears to be working, but the second one is producing the error

```
ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/sort-maps (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1559)
```

The function passes in two Map "m1 + m2" and two strings "s1 s2"
the problem piece of code is :
`(if-not (= (get map1 s2)(s1))`

What i am trying to do is see if string "s1" equals the string from value at "map s2" but i keep getting that error.  This is the function i have

```
(defn sort-maps [map1 map2 s2 s1]
  (if-not (contains? map1 s2)
    [(assoc map1 s2 s1) map2]
    [map1 (assoc map2 s2 s1)])

  (if-not (= (get map1 s2)(s1))
    [(dissoc map2 (get map1 s2))]
    [map1 (assoc map2 s2 s1)]))
```

My input:

```
"door" "rood" "odor" "pen" "list" "silt" "#"
```

My output i want would be:

```
{"enp" "pen"}
```

As i only want to return words that cannot be made up into any other word in the input

Comment: For a solution, [see my answer to the question by your classmate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116833/empty-maps-in-clojure/35117368)

Comment: The input does not match what `sort-maps` expects. What `map1`, `map2`, `s2` and `s1` are for the output `{"enp" "pen"}`?

Answer (score 2):

`s1` is a string, but by wrapping it in parens, you're making a function call. A string isn't a function, so that's why you're seeing the type error.

You probably want `(if-not (= (get map1 s2) s1))`

But you seem to have a deeper misunderstanding. Clojure data structures are **immutable**. This means the following:

```
user=> (def my-map {:a 1 :b 2})
#'user/my-map
user=> (assoc my-map :c 3)
{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3}
user=> my-map
{:a 1, :b 2}
user=> (dissoc my-map :a 1)
{:b 2}
user=> my-map
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

So you can't just change a value in place like you can with ruby or some other language.

Comment: if i do that i wont be able to use `[(dissoc map2 (get map1 s2))]` for the outcome of the if will i?

Comment: Why not? Maybe you should edit your question to explain what you think is happening here, as well as an example input and output you're expecting. I think you have a deeper misunderstanding that I'm not seeing yet.

Comment: This is what im trying to achieve is passing in strings such as "door" "rood" "odor" "pen" "list" "silt" and i want to only return "pen" as all others can be made into another word in the input

Answer (score 2):

munk rightly pointed out to the source of your error: `(s1)` tells Clojure to invoke `s1` as a function with no arguments. However, even after fixing this, your code is unlikely to do what you expect it to do.

This is the body of the function `sort-maps` (with munk's correction):

```
(if-not (contains? map1 s2)
    [(assoc map1 s2 s1) map2]
    [map1 (assoc map2 s2 s1)])

(if-not (= (get map1 s2) s1)
    [(dissoc map2 (get map1 s2))]
    [map1 (assoc map2 s2 s1)])
```

The first `if-not` statement is executed and the result (either a pair of updated `map1` and `map2` or a pair of `map1` and updated `map2`) is thrown away. Since maps in Clojure are immutable, `assoc` isn't going to add a new entry into the existing map - a new map is created instead. So, this function body is completely equivalent to just

```
(if-not (= (get map1 s2) s1)
    [(dissoc map2 (get map1 s2))]
    [map1 (assoc map2 s2 s1)])
```

I am not sure what you are doing here, so can't help you further.

Comment: I keep getting a problem i had previously with that where i just get this returned `([{}] [{}] [{}] [{}] [{}] [{}] [{}])`  What i am doing is passing in strings such as `"door" "rood" "odor" "pen" "list" "silt"` and i want to only return "pen" as all others can be made into another word in the input

Comment: @Freeman can you please post it as "input -> expected output" for function `sort-maps`. I see the input should consist of two maps and two objects (strings?). And it seems that output should be a pair of somehow updated maps. But I can't deduce anything else. So, if you can provide expected results on known input, it would help.

Comment: I have editied to show input/output, there may be another to solve the problem but i cant see why this method wouldnt work.